# can i start a thread when start the rails server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, multithreading, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

i am new in rails, i need to run one task in rails, that means have one function, which needs to call with in a 5 minutes of time interval? Because i am working with a prototype, and its running on heroku, i couldn't run any paid addons with heroku, also i read that, heroku have one scheduler, its free, but that only work with a 10 minutes interval of time. so i am thinking of, run a thread for this prototype project, ie

here writing one thread, that needs to call a function after a 5 minutes sleep? also how can i run that thread when starting the rails server? can i start that thread and server via the proc file? is this the correct way to do this?

```
def test

end
t = Thread.new do
  while true do
  sleep 60
    test()       
  end
end
t.join
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you should use some cronjob gem like [whenever](https://github.com/javan/whenever)

This gem will create a file in `config/schedule.rb`. Using this file you can call any rake task, run commands or even can call methods of classes.

For example:

```
every 10.minutes do
   # run rake task or call some class's method
end
```

But if you insist not using cronjob related gem then you should use some gem like [foreman](https://github.com/ddollar/foreman)

It's easy to use. you can learn it from [this blog](http://blog.daviddollar.org/2011/05/06/introducing-foreman.html) or [this railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/281-foreman)

**EDIT:**

This [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14413361/how-to-create-thread-at-rails-startup) might help you further...

**LATEST EDIT:**

Yes it's possible see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8619754/whenever-gem-running-cron-jobs-on-heroku). It suggest using [this add-ons](https://addons.heroku.com/scheduler#standard) and it's free :)

Comment: yes, i had tried this for another application, but these will work on heroku for free?